# Is it possible to add new paths or edit existing ones from vector drawable using java?

Tags: java, android, svg

I'm developing a music android app. I made sheet music using svg and some musical notes. Once I import the svg to android studio, it is converted to vector drawable. And I don't find any way to edit this vector drawable to edit/add paths to this vector drawable using java.

```
<vector android:height="50dp" android:viewportHeight="20.419966"
android:viewportWidth="327.61066" android:width="710dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android%22%3E
<path android:fillColor="#00000000"
    android:pathData="m0.249,20.171 l327.113,0"
    android:strokeAlpha="1" android:strokeColor="#000000"
    android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeLineJoin="round" android:strokeWidth="0.4981322"/>
```

Comment: There is no way to update a VectorDrawable in code.  You can always draw your staves, then draw each note afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio once you have imported the drawable you can only then edit the XML. If you want to change the SVG in a different way then you would need to edit it in a different program and then import it as a different drawable, or delete the old one and import it as that drawable.

You can combine drawables in different ways in XML many ways. One way is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/first_icon"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/second_icon"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

You can also change colors of drawables/SVG in Java and in the XML. I would need to know what you are trying to do to further help.